# Passing specific props along with a catch all prop in React function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So say I have a super basic component like this:

```
function MyComponent({ setIsOpen })
{
   return (
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}></button>
   )
}
```

What is the proper syntax to pass any additional unknown props onto the component, something like so:

```
function MyComponent({ setIsOpen })
{
   return (
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)} {...props}></button>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment above linked to an example. Here it is in case the link breaks:

```
function MyComponent(props)
{
   const {setIsOpen} = {...props};
   return (
      <button {...props} onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}></button>
   )
}
```